# Recommended decibel (dB) for audio files in your Android app?

Tags: android, audio

I am creating my own audio track in [Garageband](https://www.apple.com/mac/garageband/) for an Android app and wondered what is a good decibel (dB) level to set my master volume at before I export the file to mp3. Right now, it seems to be 5.5 is a decent range, but then when playing an app, one has to think about where you play it, if it's in a busy area, surely you won't hear much. But then if it's too high, there is danger of clipping (distortion).

But is there some kind of standard volume measured in decibels that developers use? Even using 5.5 dB is with the master volume almost all the way up in Garageband, yet I have read in Garageband sometimes there are low-volume problems with exports. Thanks.

Comment: What you seem to be asking about is known as dynamic range, which is the ratio between the loudest and quietest pieces. You should read the wikipedia article on the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range. When mixing music, recording engineers typically employ dynamic range compression to decrease the dynamic range. This has the effect of making the quieter parts a louder.

Comment: thanks! i will look into this and see what i can find.

Comment: I'm sure garage band has a compressor effect - have a look.